# Get scholarship vs have gotten scholarship

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> Ashley promised herself that she won't talk to her cousins unless she **gets** the scholarship.

Vs

> Ashley promised herself that she won't talk to her cousins unless she **has gotten** the scholarship.

Also

> Please call me after **you reach** the office.

Vs

> Please call me after **you've reached** the office.

What difference does the use of present perfect or present simple make in the meaning of the sentence in the above examples. And which one sounds more natural ?

Comment: She **promised** herself that she **wouldn't** talk to her cousins.

Answer (score 0):

There is little difference if any.  The perfect tenses are often simply affectations of a particular dialect, or personal style. Perfect tenses can sound a little more formal, and consequently make the speaker sound slightly more educated or "posh".

I, personally, like using the perfect tenses, but I have never liked "gotten", and try not to use it.  Where possible, I substitute "received".

> ... unless **she's received** the scholarship

Still, in these kind of situations, there are times when I use the simple present, and other times when I use the present perfect.  Unfortunately I can't tell you my thought process behind this, other than one *sounds* better in that context.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> Please call me when you reach the office.
>
> Please call me when | after you've reached the office.

I wouldn't say:

> Please call me after you reach the office.

But many native speakers would do so.

Comment: And I'm one of the native speakers who WOULD say "Please call me after you reach the office". It is perfectly idiomatic English.